# My Dataframe contains 500 columns, but I only want to pick out 27 columns in a new Dataframe. How do I do that?

Tags: pandas

My Dataframe contains 500 columns, but I only want to pick out 27 columns in a new Dataframe.
How do I do that?

I used query()
but output
TypeError: query() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 27 were given

Comment: `l = list_of_those_27_cols` then `df[l]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select the columns based on their name, you can do the following:

```
df_new = df[["colA", "colB", "colC", ...]]
```

or use the "filter" function:

```
df_new = df.filter(["colA", "colB", "colC", ..])
```

In case that your column selection is based on the index of columns:

```
df_new = df.iloc[:, 0:27] # if columns are consecutive 
df_new = df.iloc[:, [0,2,10,..]] # if columns are not consecutive (the numbers refer to the column indices)
```